# Some objects not returning from query since package name change

Tags: android, object, parse-platform, package, whitespace

I submitted a question yesterday about issues I am having since i changed my package name which Google said i needed to do.  In addendum to that question and upon further testing I have narrowed the problem down.

The problem is that in one Parse class, and only this one class, i have a small group of objects that wont return anything in the query.  Anything i add  into that class, for that one class only, adding that particular objects name, will not return from the query within the given constraint.  Only for those few new objects added and only for that object name only.  Anything NEW i add to any other class displays properly.

Let me explain further.  I have a column titled Name.  I have a column titled Recipe. In the Name column I have several Bread, Eggs, and Bacon objects.  Any NEW objects i add with the title of Bread or Bacon with objects in the Recipe column appears in the application correctly.  Anything NEW i add under Eggs with objects in the Recipe column does not return the objects in the Recipe column from the query.  All of the OLD Eggs with its associated Recipe objects data that was there before I changed the package name returns OK.  Its just the NEW data I have been adding since around the time i changed the package name that is not returning from the query.  And ONLY for the Eggs objects.

Now, I'm not sure if changing the package name had anything to do with this.  It may not.  But that's around the time this all started happening.  And only for Eggs.

I have double checked possible whitespace errors.  I have double checked spelling errors.  I am not sure whats wrong but if i figure it out I will post it here.  Its just weird this is only happening with Eggs.

Comment: The class must be directly related to the package name.  It may resolve correctly in the code.  But it may have been generated automatically at compile time, previously.  Meaning, the package name in that "cached" file may still be wrong.  Have you tried "cleaning" the project?  Or totally deleting all the automatically generated files?

Comment: I will try deleting all cached files next.   I did not think about that.   Thank you :)

Comment: Nothing is working correctly.  It is something about these particular objects. Anything new I add outside of these objects is fine. Anything inside the new objects does not show.  Still diagnosing but this is frustrating.  Sorry for the delay getting back to you.

Comment: No need to apologize to me.  If you are still having trouble, I suggest putting a bounty on the question.

Comment: I was able to bypass the problem.  I still do not know what happened but i  reentered the data as new objects and now it works fine.

Comment: SOLVED:  the problem was the limit of 100.  Changed the limit to 1000 and it runs perfectly.  Thank you all for the help  :)